# selenium webdriver from flask and save_screenshot doesnt work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, flask, apache2

So am trying to run this script (running on digital ocean apache2) , it runs succesfully with no errors but the screenshot doesnt show up anywhere in the server files.The following code is from __ init __.py

```
 @app.route('/process')
 def process():

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1366x768")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver_old')
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

Comment: did you tried with an absolute path as parameter ?

Comment: @PRMoureu yeah just tried this "driver.save_screenshot("/var/www/html/.../screnshot.png") " but still no luck

Comment: I was able to get it your code working with just modifying `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`

Comment: @Barney did it save a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, it did. The default location is the path from where you are running the python script.

Comment: @Barney am running my python  script from a digital ocean droplet on apache2, so the issue might be that it doenst have access to the directory, but should that out put an error or some kind?

Comment: You should be using `ChromeOptions`. You may also need to add the `--disable-gpu` option as well. The selenium docs also state you should use a full path with `save_screenshot`